# How to remove a file named "\" in clearcase vob directory?

Tags: clearcase

I have one file named "`\`" in a directory.
How does it got created, I have no idea.
And this file is creating problem with merge. I am not able to delete this file.

I tried option `--` to delete this but nothing works

```
ct rmname -- \
```

It just ends with

```
>
```

Also the `ct ls` shows

```
\@@/main/branch_457/1   Rule: .../branch_457/LATEST
```

Please suggest how can this type of file  can be deleted.

Answer (score 0, accepted):

If you are on Unix, you can try and follow the directives from "[About special characters in file names on UNIX and Linux](http://www-01.ibm.com/support/docview.wss?uid=swg21117471)"

```
ct rmname '/'
```

Or try escaping the special character:

```
ct rmname \/
```

On Windows, the escape character is '`^`' (as mentioned in [`cleartool` help page](http://publib.boulder.ibm.com/infocenter/cchelp/v7r0m0/index.jsp?topic=/com.ibm.rational.clearcase.hlp.doc/cc_main/c_hood_cleartool_cli.htm)):

```
ct rmname ^/
```

Comment: Thanks VonC, the file was deleted with ct rmname '\'. I was using double quotes to delete this like ct rmname "\" but that was failing :(